# Code is completing, but data isn't populating

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dashboard

I am attempting to pull data from a Transportation Sheet (D2:K) into a table on a Dashboard Sheet (U7:AB). The data will be filtered by the date on the Transportation Sheet (C2:C) based on the date range found on the Dashboard Sheet (D2:D3). Then, the data will be filtered by unconfirmed rides, which will be seen as "FALSE" in K2:K on the Transportation Sheet. I also would like the data in Dashboard Sheet's columns Y7:Y and AB7:AB to show as checkboxes, this data would be pulled by the checkboxes in the Transportation Sheet's columns H2:H and K2:K.

Script for this function:
This script is completing but nothing populates, even though the data is aligned and I have test rows saying 'False' in column K of the transportation sheet.

```
function fetchDataFromSheet1() {
  var transportationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Transportation");
  var dashboardSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var unconfirmedFilter = "False"; // Update with the desired transportation option

  var dashboardDate = dashboardSheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
  var transportationData = transportationSheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues();

  var filteredData = transportationData.filter(function(row) {
    var transportationDate = row[0]; // Assuming dates are in column C (index 0)
      return (
      transportationDate instanceof Date &&
      transportationDate.toDateString() === dashboardDate.toDateString()
    );
  });

  var data = transportationSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var filteredData = data.filter(function(row) {
  return row[10] === unconfirmedFilter; // Filter based on column K (index 10)
  });

  // Check if filteredData is empty
  if (filteredData.length === 0) {
    return; // Exit the function without making any changes
  }

  // Write filtered data from Transportation to Dashboard starting from row 7 and column U
  targetSheet.getRange(7, 21, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);

  // Insert checkboxes in column Y (index 25) and column AB (index 28)
  var checkboxRangeY = targetSheet.getRange(7, 25, filteredData.length, 1);
  checkboxRangeY.insertCheckboxes();

  var checkboxRangeAB = targetSheet.getRange(7, 28, filteredData.length, 1);
  checkboxRangeAB.insertCheckboxes();
}
```

Once this data is pulled into the Dashboard, I would like that any edits I make on the dashboard to show into the Transportation Sheet. Thought would be that if I have an unconfirmed list on the Dashboard, once I confirm the ride I would check the box in column AB on the Dashboard, which would change the related data in column K in the Transportation Sheet (making it false to true). This would then make the data show in the confirmed table found on the dashboard. However, I am still trying to figure out the right script to get that function to work in Google Sheets. Any guidance would be appreciated!

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HHX77RVjvnqzLwtA8pa0loViFXnnNOFbKuBnKqr8NXw/edit#gid=1222953402)

Comment: Use the debugger to figure what's not working.

Comment: @Cooper Unfortunately the debugger isn't coming back with anything.

Comment: The debugger allows you to set break points and single step and inspect values as you go through the program.  It doesn't find problems on its own.  It would be worth your time to learn how to use it.

Comment: @Cooper got it figured out! The breakpoints helped lead to the answer, thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Code that worked, had to put log statements:

```
function fetchDataFromSheet1() {
  var transportationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Transportation");
  var dashboardSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var unconfirmedFilter = false; // Update with the desired transportation option
  
  var dashboardStartDate = dashboardSheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
  var dashboardEndDate = dashboardSheet.getRange("D3").getValue();
  
  var transportationData = transportationSheet.getRange("C2:L").getValues();

  // Logging dashboardStartDate, dashboardEndDate, and transportationData
  Logger.log("Dashboard Start Date: " + dashboardStartDate);
  Logger.log("Dashboard End Date: " + dashboardEndDate);
  
  var filteredData = transportationData.filter(function(row) {
    var transportationDate = row[0]; // Assuming dates are in column C (index 2)
    
    // Logging transportationDate
    Logger.log("Transportation Date: " + transportationDate);
    
    return (
      transportationDate instanceof Date &&
      transportationDate >= dashboardStartDate &&
      transportationDate <= dashboardEndDate
    );
  });

  filteredData = filteredData.filter(function(row) {
    return row[8] === unconfirmedFilter; // Filter based on column K (index 8)
  });
  
  // Check if filteredData is empty
  if (filteredData.length === 0) {
    Logger.log("Filtered data is empty.");
    return; // Exit the function without making any changes
  }
  
  // Write filtered data from Transportation to Dashboard starting from row 7 and column U
  dashboardSheet.getRange(7, 20, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);
  
  // Insert checkboxes in column Y (index 25) and column AB (index 28)
  var checkboxRangeY = dashboardSheet.getRange(7, 25, filteredData.length, 1);
  checkboxRangeY.insertCheckboxes();

  var checkboxRangeAB = dashboardSheet.getRange(7, 28, filteredData.length, 1);
  checkboxRangeAB.insertCheckboxes();

  // Log the checkbox status in column K
  var checkboxStatus = filteredData.map(function(row) {
    return row[8] ? "Checked" : "Unchecked";
  });
  Logger.log("Checkbox Status (Column K): " + checkboxStatus);
}
```